# Отсутствует активный процесс используя nohup Linux PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, unix

Я запустил фоновый PHP-процесс nohup через SHH на моем сервере. Сервер на ОС Gentoo, Apache. PHP-скрипт всегда работает, даже когда я закрываю терминал. (всегда работает, потому что он делает некоторые вещи, которые я могу отслеживать в моем приложении) Вот запуск используя `nohup`

```
nohup /usr/local/bin/php7-71LATEST-CLI /kunden/310040_81369/SalesTool/makeShedule.php </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

В скрипте есть бесконечный цикл.

Теперь я хочу остановить это. Для этого мне нужно получить ID процесса, но я не могу его найти. Я пробовал разные способы получить ID без успеха. Например, с помощью процесса `ps aux` здесь нет:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
u310040  14175  0.0  0.7 438104 116748 ?       SNl  Jun27   1:08 /kunden/310040_81369/ms_appl/mysql_5.6.27/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/kunden/310040_81369/ms_appl/mysql_5.6.27/var/my.cnf --basedir=/kund
u310040  28329  0.0  0.0   8692  5048 pts/1    SNs  13:13   0:00 -bash
u310040  28487  0.0  0.0   7964  3432 pts/1    RN+  15:41   0:00 ps aux
u310040  31280  0.0  0.0   6832  2908 ?        SN   May28   0:00 /bin/sh bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/kunden/310040_81369/ms_appl/mysql_5.6.27/var/my.cnf --basedir=/kunden/310040_81369/ms_appl/mysql
```

то же самое с командой `top`

```
1702 u310040   25   5    8480   3940   3564 R   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 top
14175 u310040   28   8  438104 116748  10136 S   0.0  0.7   1:08.88 mysqld
28329 u310040   25   5    8692   5048   4540 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.17 bash
31280 u310040   28   8    6832   2908   2660 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 mysqld_safe
```

Как я могу это остановить?

Примечание: я запустил несколько раз, поэтому процессов больше чем 1

Comment: процессов в системе гораздо больше, чем то, что вы видите. Что то их скрывает, вроде системы виртуализации. Лучше узнать у своего хостера.

Comment: Возможно у пользователя `u310040` отсутствую права на просмотр всех процессов. Попробуйте проверить список процессов использую `sudo` или пройдя авторизацию под суперпользователем. `su - root` для примера

Comment: хостинг не позволяет мне пользоваться `sudo`, `apt-get` :( а поддержка просто не отвечает.

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Покажите кусок кода, который вы запускаете. Можете также привести пример запуска в одной и той же сессии: `php /my/cool/crap.php &; jobs; ps -xa`

Comment: проблема решилась на стороне хостинга. он скрывает все процессы, и как сказали, просмотр с моей стороны не возможен. хостинг предоставил список процессов, после чего они были успешно завершены.

Comment: Так как проблема с хостингом решилась, можно поподробней. Вы вообше не видите запущенных процессов, а как вы их завершали?